# The better object view to a sudoku squares?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sudoku

I'm developing a sudoku game in Objective C, in fact I kinda already finish it, I just have to adjust something of design and make a window view, somethings like that. But i'm still learning about iOS, so a I don't know what object view is the better to use in this case.

I'm using buttons to make the sudoku squares, but I wanna put in my game the possibility to make notes on the top of the squares with the possibilites that are available in that square, but the button view only have title propriety...

What view should I use instead of buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a custom `UIView` subclass and initialize it with a `UILabel` on top and a `UIButton` covering all of it.